# angular 2 s-multiselect-dropdown not working inside the form element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to use a multi-select in Angular 2 but I have not found a multi-select which works normally.

1. `ng2-complete` (does not call `onselect` function when inside the form)
2. `ss-multiselect-dropdown`(does not call `ngModelChange` when inside the form)
3. `angular2-multiselect` (does not show style well when inside the form)

I need to use form element because I want to validate control

The  `s-multiselect-dropdown` MultiSelect and Filter mode also does not work.

```
       <form #f="ngForm" novalidate>  
                <ss-multiselect-dropdown [options]="paymentTypeInfo"                                     
                  [ngModel]="selectedTexts"  (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" >
                 </ss-multiselect-dropdown>
           <button type="submit" class="button"(click)=savePersonDetails(f.valid)>Submit</button>
            <form/>
              paymentTypeInfo: PaymentTypeInfo[] = [];
              selectedTexts: number[] = [];
                   this.PaymentTypeInfo= [
                        { "id": 1, "name": "India" },
                        { "id": 2, "name": "Singapore" },
                        { "id": 3, "name": "Australia" },
                        { "id": 4, "name": "Canada" },
                        { "id": 5, "name": "South Korea" },
                        { "id": 6, "name": "Germany" },
                        { "id": 7, "name": "France" },
                        { "id": 8, "name": "Russia" },
                        { "id": 9, "name": "Italy" },
                        { "id": 10, "name": "Sweden" }
                    ];
       savePersonDetails(isValid: boolean) {          
            if (isValid)
              {
                 console.log("selectedTexts");
                console.log(this.selectedTexts);
              }
            }
 public onChange(): void {
        alert("hi");
      console.log(this.selectedTexts);
   }
```

Comment: Please include your html and angular code

Comment: please share your code

Comment: The way you closed your <form> tag is wrong. Close form tag as </form> instead of <form/>

Answer (score 0):

I helped someone fix their problems with drop downs in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dIS2GJdcA8OiPZU4jD4C?p=preview). Maybe it can give you some inspiration

listcomponent.html

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="#number of numbers">
    <td>
      <label>Country:</label>
      <select [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry[number].id"
        (ngModelChange)="onSelect($event, number)">
          <option value="0">--Select--</option>
          <option *ngFor="#country of countries" 
            value={{country.id}}>{{country.name}}
          </option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <label>State:</label>
        <select>
          <option *ngIf='selectedCountry[number].id == 0' 
              value="0">--Select--</option>
          <option *ngFor="#state of states[number]" 
              value={{state.id}}>{{state.name}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

listcomponent.ts

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { DataService } from './dataservice';
import { Country } from './country';
import { State } from './state';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-country-list',
  templateUrl: 'app/countrylistcomponent.html',
  providers: [DataService]
})
export class CountryListComponent {
  selectedCountry:Country[] = [new Country(0, 'India'),
                               new Country(0, 'India'),
                               new Country(0, 'India')]; 
  countries: Country[];
  states: State[] = [[] as State[],[] as State[],[] as State[]] 

  constructor(private _dataService: DataService) {
     this.numbers = Array(3).fill().map((x,i)=>i);
     this.countries = this._dataService.getCountries();
  }

  onSelect(value,index) {
    this.states[index] = this._dataService.getStates().
        filter((item)=> item.countryid == value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Correct your closing form tag

`form` tag is closed as `</form>` not as `<form/>`

**2.** Correct usage of ngModel

Used `ngModel` as `[(ngModel)]` instead of `[ngModel]`

**3.** If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

Update your `s-multiselect-dropdown` to include a name attribute as follow

```
<ss-multiselect-dropdown [options]="paymentTypeInfo"                                     
[(ngModel)]="selectedTexts"  (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" name="select">
```

**Correct Code is**

```html
<form #f="ngForm" novalidate>  
       <ss-multiselect-dropdown [options]="paymentTypeInfo"         
           [(ngModel)]="selectedTexts"  
           (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
           name="select">
       </ss-multiselect-dropdown>
       <button type="submit" class="button" 
            (click)=savePersonDetails(f.valid)>
            Submit</button>
<form/>
```